# Getting common value count of text array column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id   num
---  ----
1    {'1','2','3','3'}
2    {'2','3'}
3    {'5','6','7'}
```

Here `id` is a **unique** column and `num` is a **text array** which can contain duplicate elements . I want to do something like an intersection between two consecutive rows so that I get the count of common elements between `num` of two rows. Consider something like a set where duplicates are considered only once. For example, for the above table I am expecting something like the following:

```
id1   id2  count
---   ---  -----
1      2    2
1      3    0
2      1    2
2      3    0
3      1    0
3      2    0
```

It is not necessary to get the output like the above. The only part I am concerned about is `count`.

I have the following query which gives the output only for one id compared with one other id:

```
select unnest(num) from emp where id=1
intersect
select unnest(num) from emp where id=2
```

How can I generalize it to get the required output?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the duplicate values and explain how you want them counted.  And what happens when there are multiple duplicates in a pair of ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the question.

Comment: . . You still have data that the previous answer -- using `count(distinct)` -- will produce the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward approach puts the intersection of the unnested arrays in a subquery and gets their count.

```
SELECT t1.id id1,
       t2.id id2,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM (SELECT num1.num
                            FROM unnest(t1.num) num1(num)
                     INTERSECT
                     SELECT num2.num
                            FROM unnest(t2.num) num2(num)) x) count
       FROM emp t1
            INNER JOIN emp t2
                       ON t2.id > t1.id
       ORDER BY t1.id,
                t2.id;
```

Should you be only interested in whether the arrays share elements or not but not in the exact count, you can also use the overlap operator `&&`.

```
SELECT t1.id id1,
       t2.id id2,
       t1.num && t2.num intersection_not_empty
       FROM emp t1
            INNER JOIN emp t2
                       ON t2.id > t1.id
       ORDER BY t1.id,
                t2.id;
```

Comment: That first part of your answer is exactly what I needed.Thanks!

Comment: Just so that anyone in the future doesn't get confused, can you please  change the table name as I have updated that in my question?

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, this works:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1000, array['acct', 'hr']), (1005, array['dev', hr'])) v(empid, depts)
     )
select t1.empid, t2.empid,
       (select count(distinct d1)
        from unnest(t1.depts) d1 join
             unnest(t2.depts) d2
             on d1 = d2
       ) cnt
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.empid < t2.empid;
```

I'm not 100% sure this is what you intend, though.